# Kubernetes mountPropagation clarifications

Tags: docker, kubernetes, volumes

I have a docker image A that contains a folder I need to share with another container B in the same K8s pod.

At first I decided to use a shared volume (emptyDir) and launched A as an init container to copy all the content of the folder into the shared volume. This works fine.

Then looking at k8s doc I realised I could use [mountPropagation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#mount-propagation) between the containers.
So I changed the initContainer to a plain container (side car) in the same pod and performed a mount of the container A folder I want to share with container B. This works fine but I need to keep the container running A up with a wait loop. Or not...

Then I decided to come back to the InitContainer pattern and do the same, meaning mount the folder in A inside the shared volume and then the container finishes cause it is an InitContainer and then use the newly mounted folder in container B. And it works !!!!

So my question is, can someone explains me if this is expected on all Kubernetes clusters ? and explain to me why the mounted folder from A that is no longer running as a container can still be seen by my other container ?

Here is a simple manifest to demonstrate it.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: testvol
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: busybox-init
      image: busybox
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "mkdir -p /opt/connectors; echo \"bar\" > /opt/connectors/foo.txt;  mkdir -p /opt/connectors_new; mount --bind /opt/connectors /opt/connectors_new; echo connectors mount is ok"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: connectors
          mountPath: /opt/connectors_new
          mountPropagation: Bidirectional

  containers:
    - name: busybox
      image: busybox
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "cat /opt/connectors/foo.txt; trap : TERM INT; (while true; do sleep 1000; done) & wait"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: connectors
          mountPath: /opt/connectors
          mountPropagation: HostToContainer
  volumes:
    - name: connectors
      emptyDir: {}
```

here the manifest to reproduce the behavior

Comment: Can you give an example of your final working config?  The mount-propagation option you describe looks like it controls how Linux mounts work within volumes, so it'd be pretty unusual to need it at all.  (If you can `COPY --from=image-a` in image B's Dockerfile, that's best, and if not, the `emptyDir` volume you describe is the standard approach.)

Comment: What do you mean "this is expected on all Kubernetes clusters?" ? If it will works in any K8s cluster, such as self-managed/as-a-service, or in any vesion?. Could you please post the yaml file? I will try to replicate in my lab environment.

Comment: I have edited the post to add a manifest to reproduce it, I am desperate for some explanation. This would definitly save the time for copying data from A to the shared volume

Comment: @DavidMaze adding those file statically into B docker image is really less flexible cause they have different lifecycles and we want to be able to update those A images without updating B image. Using a docker image as a volume is so simple with docker compose and so complicated with K8s, although it seems not.

Comment: What you've shown looks like the normal `emptyDir` volume setup, with extra `mountPropagation:` options; I don't think they make a difference here.  How is this different from your first attempt?

Comment: (In plain Docker/Compose you need all this logic too, since the volume only gets populated by the first container to start up and its content never ever gets updated unless the application does it on its own.)

Comment: @DavidMaze hum, the first attemps was copying the files from A to the shared volume, the manifest above is creating a folder (and a file) inside A, mounting this folder on the shared volume and then die (Initicontainer), then the file is still accessible from container B !!

Comment: I'm not sure if i can understand well what you want, but my guess is, as the volume `connectors` is commom for both container in the pod, it will use the same "volume area" in both, this is the reason you can see the file in the container B after the container A (initContainer) dies. What is the behaviour you expect?

Answer (score 0):

This works because your containers run in a pod. The pod is where your volume is defined, not the container. So you are creating a volume in your pod that is an empty directory. Then you are mounting it in your init container and making changes. That makes changes to the volume on the pod.

Then when your init container finishes, the files at the pod level don't go away, they are still there, so your second container picks up the files when it mounts the same volume from the pod.

This is expected behavior and doesn't need mountPropagation fields at all. The mountPropagation fields may have some effect on emptyDir volumes, but it is not related to preserving the files:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir

> All containers in the Pod can read and write the same files in the emptyDir volume, though that volume can be mounted at the same or different paths in each container. When a Pod is removed from a node for any reason, the data in the emptyDir is deleted permanently.
>
> Note: A container crashing does not remove a Pod from a node. The data in an emptyDir volume is safe across container crashes.

The note here doesn't explicitly state it, but this implies it is also safe across initContainer to Container transitions. As long as your pod exists on the node, your data will be there in the volume.